# intellij 12 ultimate does not recognize less file types?

Tags: intellij-idea, less

it seems to me that intellij does not recognize less files, [even though they state that they support less file types](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/file-types-recognized-by-intellij-idea.html)

Am I missing something? the less compiler is bundled but they cannot recognize the less syntax?

[image: The less file type does not show up as well in the file types of intellij 12]

Comment: Is there another plugin that is necessary to enable - something about Web? Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin called `Less Support` already bundled in your installation, you should enable it.

Comment: i am new to intellij, somehow I thought that when it is bundled, it means it is actually enabled as well

Answer (score 1):

Although the Less plugin was activated I had this issue in a Scala Play app.

The reason was that IntelliJ didn't associate Less files with Less but rather with CSS.

The solution was to tell IntelliJ to treat files ending with `.less` as Less files:

Go to `Settings` → `File Types` → `Less` and register `*.less` as a pattern:

[image: let less files be recognized by their file extension]

Then mark the file as `Less` (you might need to mark the file as plaintext first):

[image: mark file as less]